# SortedList keys all point to the same value

Tags: c#, dictionary, xna, textures

In my code I enter 4 keys with different values into a SortedList, each using:

```
animations.Add(0, new Animation("prefix", textures, timer, looped));
```

The sorted list is created like this:

```
private SortedList<int, Animation> animations = new SortedList<int, Animation>();
```

However, when I call to change the current Animation being played it changes the Key being read (the ID), but not the value. The value always stays on the last one entered into the SortedList.

This is the change Animation method:

```
    private void setAnimation(int ID)
    {
        Utilities.Log("Animation set to: " + ID + " of " + animations.Count);
        curAnim = animations[ID];
        curAnimID = ID;
        curAnim.reset();
    }
```

Which outputs

```
[29/07/2013 08:09:00 PM] Animation set to: 1 of 4
[29/07/2013 08:09:01 PM] Animation set to: 4 of 4
```

But the visual Animation always stays the same. The changes are triggered by keyboard events.

I've been stuck on this all day, if you could help that'd be greatly appreciated. Any other parts of the code will be provided on request.

EDITS: curAnim is being shown by a method called getTexture() in the Animation class, which always returns as if it's that of the last entry entered.

Inserts:

```
        //----------------IDLE----------------//
        TextureBank idleTb = new TextureBank();
        idleTb.add("idle1", c.Load<Texture2D>("idle"));
        idleTb.add("idle1" + flip_str, Utilities.FlipHorizontal(c.Load<Texture2D>("characters/wife/idle")));
        animations.Add(ANIMATIONS.IDLE, new Animation("idle", idleTb, 200, true));

        //----------------JUMP----------------//
        TextureBank jumpTb = new TextureBank();
        jumpTb.add("jump1", c.Load<Texture2D>("jump"));
        jumpTb.add("jump1" + flip_str, Utilities.FlipHorizontal(c.Load<Texture2D>("characters/wife/jump")));
        animations.Add(ANIMATIONS.JUMP, new Animation("jump", jumpTb, 200, false));

        //----------------PUNCH----------------//
        TextureBank punchTb = new TextureBank();
        punchTb.add("punch1", c.Load<Texture2D>("punch"));
        punchTb.add("punch1" + flip_str, Utilities.FlipHorizontal(c.Load<Texture2D>("characters/wife/punch")));
        animations.Add(ANIMATIONS.PUNCH, new Animation("punch", punchTb, 200, false));

        //----------------WALK----------------//
        TextureBank walkTb = new TextureBank();
        walkTb.add("walk1", c.Load<Texture2D>("walk"));
        walkTb.add("walk1" + flip_str, Utilities.FlipHorizontal(c.Load<Texture2D>("characters/wife/walk")));
        walkTb.add("walk2", c.Load<Texture2D>("walk2"));
        walkTb.add("walk2" + flip_str, Utilities.FlipHorizontal(c.Load<Texture2D>("characters/wife/walk2")));
        animations.Add(ANIMATIONS.WALK, new Animation("walk", walkTb, 200, true));

        setAnimation(ANIMATIONS.IDLE);
```

Comment: How are you propagating `curAnim` to your UI? curAnim is probably set correctly but your UI is probably still a reference to the one that was originally set.

Comment: By "value doesn't change" I mean that when requesting the prefix from a key it return the same as the last SortedList entry defined.

Comment: `animations.Add(0, new Animation(...))` Do you always use zero, `0`? You can add only *one* entry for each `int` in a `SortedList<int, WhatEver>`.

Comment: After you've set the animation, output a log that has the new current animation name or id or something. Like `Utilities.Log("Current animation is " + curAnim.Name);` (or whatever property the `"prefix"` is). That will tell you if the collection is broken, or if your code to update the current animation display is broken.

Comment: @McAden I use a method called getTexture() from the Animation class which returns the required texture to be drawn and each time it refers to the last entry entered

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen No, it changes each time based on constants in another class

Comment: Sounds like you're creating a texture, inserting it, reusing the texture, inserting it again etc, overwriting the texture each time. Create a new one each time and you'll most likely be fine.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The 4 entries have different variables for each part, but each entry returns the variables for the last entered.

Comment: Could you show the loop that actually inserts the values?

Comment: I think @JoachimIsaksson is right. Are you mutating the same `Animation` instance and inserting it over and over again? Is `Animation` a class or a struct? Do you create a distinct instance each time with a `new` object expression?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It's in the main post now.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen It's a class

Comment: @Rob Whatever it is, create a new instance of it before each load. Looks like you're loading data into it, adding it to the texture bank, overwriting the data with the next file and so on.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That's just how it loads content. I have tested it all and it works. Changing out the `TextureBank`s into the last entry makes it stuck on that bank.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson `c` or `Animation`?

Comment: @Rob `c` is the one being reused, it is most likely the problem. Add a `c = new <whatevertheclassis>()` before each load and test.

Comment: Agreed, it looks like you are adding c to the list which is a reference type, then you are changing the texture of c on the next load.

Comment: does the c.Load method have a return type?

Comment: @DavidC c.Load just converts a file on my computer to a Class specified. I doubt it's the problem.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that [this is the `Load<Texture2D>()` method being called](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197848.aspx)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Just passed through some more to test it. The problem stayed, unfortunately.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, really helps to know more than "a class" :)

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't think so, Each `TextureBank` can be switched out and still work, but it's only the last entry that gets stuck.

Comment: @Rob: You mean that isn't the `Load<Texture2D>()` method you're using, or are you talking about someone else's comment?

Comment: @Rob what is the Type of c?  are you storing c in your Dictionary after it "loads" the texture, or is it returning a texture that is stored in the Dictionary?

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't think `Load<Texture2D>()` is the problem.

Comment: @Rob does the value of all TextureBanks textures = walk2

Comment: Define 'only last entry that gets stuck'

Comment: @DavidC walk1, walk2 and the flipped versions are the only textures retrievable

Comment: Are you saying that jumpTb["jump1"] returns the texture for walk1?  Or does the animations collection only contain 1 animation / texturebank, that of "walk"?

Comment: @DavidC jumpTb returns the textures that were added into them. It's when the Animation class looks for the texturebank and prefix that was given to it, it acts like it's the "walk" Animation class.

Comment: How are you assigning an Enum to an Integer type? VS is giving me a compile time error asking for a cast.

Answer (score 0):

If `setAnimation` is called from a different thread than the one reading from `curAnim`, then you need some locking to ensure that the display thread actually starts using the updated value.  Otherwise it can happily keep using the prior animation object forever, long after you think you've replaced it.